# How to delete reversed value on Oracle Database by using Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say i have some data on Oracle database like what i mentioned above .

TABLE

```
       COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | Quantity

        100    |  2000   |     1
       2000    |  100    |     5
       3000    |  100    |     2
```

As you can see column1 and column2 is reversed data . What is the efficient way to clean this data from oracleDb . I am not concerned about which one might delete . My main purpose is if table includes reverse data  one of them should be deleted . It is enough for me .

Comment: As per your example there is another column quantity which varies for the first two rows. Are you sure this is duplicated data?

Comment: Accutally i am not corcerned about quantity. column1 and column2 are reversed . That is the problem for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of doing it is using `EXISTS` as shown in the following example:

**Oracle Data setup:**

> ```
> SQL> CREATE TABLE TBL (COL1, COL2, QUANTITY)
>   2  AS SELECT * FROM
>   3  (
>   4  SELECT 100, 2000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   5  SELECT 2000, 100, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   6  SELECT 3000, 100, 2 FROM DUAL
>   7  );
>
> Table created.
> ```

**Current data:**

> ```
> SQL> SELECT * FROM TBL;
>
>       COL1       COL2   QUANTITY
> ---------- ---------- ----------
>        100       2000          1
>       2000        100          5
>       3000        100          2
> ```

**Query to delete the duplicate:**

> ```
> SQL> DELETE FROM TBL T
>   2  WHERE EXISTS (
>   3          SELECT 1
>   4          FROM TBL TIN
>   5          WHERE T.COL1 = TIN.COL2
>   6              AND T.COL2 = TIN.COL1
>   7              AND T.ROWID > TIN.ROWID
>   8      );
>
> 1 row deleted.
> ```

**Current view of the data:**

> ```
> SQL> SELECT * FROM TBL;
>
>       COL1       COL2   QUANTITY
> ---------- ---------- ----------
>        100       2000          1
>       3000        100          2
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Let me call your table T.

```
select *
from T T1 join T T2
     on T1.column1 = T2.column2
     and T1.column2 = T2.column1;
```

Gives you the pairs.
Each pair occurs twice, because of the symmetry.

In order to delete them, you can do

```
delete from T
where rowid in (
    select T1.rowid
    from T T1 join T T2
         on T1.column1 = T2.column2
         and T1.column2 = T2.column1
    where T1.rowid < T2.rowid
);
```

Note: I didn't test this. I leave that up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the data in many ways.  I might suggest:

```
delete from t
    where t.col1 > t.col2 or
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.col1 = t.col2 and t2.col2 = t.col1
                 );
```

Then . . . the more important thing.  Prevent this from happening in the future with a unique constraint/index:

```
create unique index unq_t_col1_col2 on
     t(least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2));
```

Actually, I would fix the data so `col1 < col2` always and add the constraints:

```
unique (col1, col2),
check (col1 < col2)
```

Nothing like keeping the data clean to keep your database safe.